# angular and jQuery conflict with $

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've read many similar questions to this on Stack but I haven't been able to solve my issue. I have a angular module and controller which works fine *before* I include the jQuery library. When I include it (before angular lib is included), I get

```
Error: $scope.markersEvent is undefined
```

and when in the controller I have console.log($) i get

```
function jQuery()
```

My understanding is that if I include Angular *after* jQuery there should be no conflict because Angular "takes" the $. Still, I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">var j = $.noConflict();</script>
```

And console.log($) will show

```
undefined
```

**What should I do to have Angular using $ and jQuery using, say, jq?** Sorry, I'm rather new at Angular.

Code:
Index.html

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=""><!-- for removing favicon error -->     
<!-- script references -->
<script src="externals/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var j = $.noConflict();</script>
<script src="externals/angularjs/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="externals/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="externals/angularjs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="externals/angularjs/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="externals/angularjs/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
<script src="externals/angularjs/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/partials/eventJoin/eventJoin.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/partials/eventCreate/eventCreate.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/directives/header-menu/header-menu.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/directives/header-login/header-login.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/directives/event-type-choose/event-type-choose.module.js"></script> 
<script src="app/components/directives/sidebar-event-list/sidebar-event-list.module.js"></script>
```

eventJoin.module.js

```
angular.module('eventJoin.module', [])
//controller start
.controller('eventJoinController', function ($scope) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        //run when DOM is ready
        console.log($);
        initMap();
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.markersEvent.length; i++) {
            initMarkers($scope.markersEvent[i]); //create initial markers
        }
    });
    //Pre-load document.ready
    function initMap() {
        $scope.mapProp = {
            //karta över sverige
            center : {
                lat : 62.5421031,
                lng : 19.7477994
            },
            zoom : 5,
        };
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemap'), $scope.mapProp);
    }
    function initMarkers(info) {
        console.log("initMarkers function");
        new google.maps.Marker({
            map : $scope.map,
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.lang),
            title : "test"
        });
    }
    $scope.markersEvent = [{
            city : 'Göteborg',
            desc : 'This is the best city in the world!',
            lat : 57.716610,
            lang : 11.973904
        }, {
            city : 'Stockholm',
            desc : 'Shit city',
            lat : 59.336574,
            lang : 18.067879
        }, {
            city : 'Kiruna',
            desc : 'Shit city',
            lat : 67.858475,
            lang : 20.225530
        }
    ];
})
//END controller
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'eventJoin.module', 'eventCreate.module', 'header-menu.module', 
'header-login.module', 'event-type-choose.module', 'sidebar-event-list.module']);
    myApp.controller('appController', function() {
        var appCont = this;
        appCont.shit = "hhh";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `eventJoin.module.js` JS file included in `index.html` as a `<script>`. Include it and it should work.

Comment: sorry, it was there, I just didn't paste it here. I have added it now. Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now, at least for the time being. Following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRHnWD_2DYM), which basically does the same as the jQuery documentation for noConflict, that is, putting other libraries **before** jQuery and then calling noConflict, it works. The reason why I did not try this before is that 1. I have read that jQuery should be loaded before Angular and 2. this [link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/#including-jquery-before-other-libraries) says that if other libraries are loaded after jQuery then those will be granted the '$'-sign without the need for using noConflict.

The error is gone and the site loads as it is suppose to.