# jQuery slideDown ($.slideDown) animated error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

This simple code not working:

```
$('li a').off('click').on('click', function(e){
  var checkElement = $this.next();
  checkElement.slideDown(500, function () {
        checkElement.addClass('menu-open');
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
<li>
    <a href="unsafe:javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="fa "></i><span class="ng-binding">Level 1</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
    </a>

    <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#/level2" class="ng-scope">
                <i class="fa "></i> <span class="ng-binding">Level 2.1</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/level2" class="ng-scope">
                <i class="fa "></i> <span class="ng-binding">Level 2.2</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Debuging: `checkElement` in `var checkElement = $this.next();` It contains an array of a position with the 'ul' element sibling:
[print Chrome debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfwMA.png)

Error:

> jquery-2.2.3.min.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

The exception is thrown before executing the callback / complete function.
In jQuery the error is within the method: animate

I also have the Angular loaded.

Forgive me for bad English

Comment: `$this.next();` should be `$(this).next();`

Comment: I tried so. The same mistake.
But it should not be the problem here, as 'checkElement' is correct, with the element 'ul'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved.
It was not conflict with Angular, but with a loaded jQuery library (http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll)
When running `$.slimScroll` the`body` tag was overwritten for the slim effect in the scroll and this caused `window.document.body` to be null.
Removed library and everything working.

Answer (score 0):

`$this.next();` should be `$(this).next();`

And prefer `$('.sidebar-menu > li > a')` to point to the direct `<a>` children

```js
$('li > a').off('click').on('click', function(e){
  var checkElement = jQuery(this).next('.treeview-menu');
  checkElement.slideDown(500, function () {
        checkElement.addClass('menu-open');
  });
});
```

```css
.treeview-menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu-open {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
<li>
    <a href="unsafe:javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="fa "></i><span class="ng-binding">Level 1</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
    </a>

    <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#/level2" class="ng-scope">
                <i class="fa "></i> <span class="ng-binding">Level 2.1</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/level2" class="ng-scope">
                <i class="fa "></i> <span class="ng-binding">Level 2.2</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I appreciate that, but it is not the case.
The variable 'check Element' is with the correct element - $ this and $ (this) brings the same result

Comment: the 'ul' element is with 'display: none' already.
Changed  `$.show()` also plays the same mistake.
Maybe conflict with Anglular?

Comment: I believe the switch is not the problem. The error is in the animation.
This works: `checkElement.css ('display', 'block')`

Comment: I suspect a conflict too. Please, can you test with `jQuery` instead of `$` : `jQuery(this).next('.treeview-menu')` ? You can also check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085834/angular-and-jquery-conflict-with) but because I'm not familiar with Angular, I'm done here... sorry :(

Comment: Switching to jQuery did not work.
Probably some conflict even as out of context, the Chrome console for example, `$.slideDown` works. Only in the context of application no.
I appreciate your efforts to try help me and their readiness.

Comment: I like to understand ;). Please, when you'll fix your issue, came back here to answer to your own question.